# Typescript enum, array as value

Tags: typescript

This looks odd to me

```
enum MessageStatusGroup {
  PENDING = [1, 2, 3],
  PUBLISHED = [4],
  DRAFT = [0],
}
```

and my linter gives error
[image]

Is there any limitation in typescript that prevents specifing array as value?

Comment: This  is not linter error, it’s compiler error

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/logs/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jna and TBA are right.

But may be you can simply workaround with :

```
export const MessageStatusGroup = {
  PENDING : [1, 2, 3],
  PUBLISHED : [4],
  DRAFT : [0],
} as const;
```

It should do the trick. The 'as const' at the end will ensure immutability of MessageStatusGroup, then it can be used the same way as an enum.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in TypeScript enums, the values must be either string or number types. An array is not a valid value. This is why your linter is giving an error.

> TypeScript provides both numeric and string-based enums.

[Third line here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)

You can also point to other enums

```js
enum Foo {
  Bar = 'Baz'
}

enum PointTo {
  Bar = Foo.Bar
}
```

And for numeric enums, you can also point to functions that return numeric values.

```
const numFunc = () => 4;

enum PointTo {
  Function = numFunc()
}
```

Check out [typescriptlang](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) for more examples

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that TypeScript support [numeric and string-based](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) enums, array are not supported.